# proving a subset of Dp is cyclic for some prime p

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, dihedral-groups

Apologies if this question has been asked, I cannot seem to find it and I would greatly appreciate an explanation before my midterm tomorrow. My question reads

```
 Let p be a prime, and let H ≤ Dp be a proper subgroup (i.e., not all 
 of Dp). Show that H is cyclic.
```

My only thought was that there are only two generating elements of Dp, reflection and rotation, and so a proper subgroup we could make is only using one generating element - thus subgroup is cyclic. But this is obviously not a legitimate proof (or even legitimate logic), it ignores the possibility of using both generators and placing more restrictions on them to form a proper subgroup, and I never use the fact that Dp is an n-gon with prime n. So yea, I'm missing a lot and I can't figure out why or what it is. If I could further request a more colloquial/intuitive explanation I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: Why must a subgroup contain one of these two generators?

Comment: My understanding is that any element in our overgroup has to be contained inside our subgroup, and all elements in our overgroup are generated by these two generators, so any element in our subgroup is as well @randall

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Lagrange, any (proper) subgroup $H$ of $D_p$ must have either $2$ or $p$ elements. If $|H| = 2$ then it is obviously cyclic. Assume therefore that $|H| = p$.

Any group of prime order has, again by Lagrange, no non-trivial subgroups, so it is cyclic.

Comment: Thank you. So to be clear, if there are no nontrivial subgroups then the group must be cyclic — does this imply that in taking a proper subgroup I must lose at least one generating element from my overgroup?

Comment: That's not generally the case: consider $\Bbb Z_2 \times \Bbb Z_5$ as a subgroup of $\Bbb Z_4 \times \Bbb Z_5$, for example. So imposing more relations can give proper subgroups too.

Comment: I'd like to add that in some cases it's not obvious which presentation to give for a group -- two presentations might have a different number of generators.

Comment: @saucin' I hope your midterm went well. Please consider accepting my answer so the question gets taken off the "unanswered" list and we both get some sweet sweet reputation points.

Comment: Oh yes thank you, I’m still kinda new to this :)